# how to divide an int over and over by the same number as long as its mod 0

Tags: java, algorithm, primes

I need to create an algorithm. The algorithm takes an int and gives back an array. It is supposed to divide the int as long as the remainder is zero. If it's no longer divisible it should do the same with the next number.(The numbers are 2, 3,5... all prime numbers)

Here is an example of what I am trying to explain.
Number: 5
Array to give back: {5}

Number: 16
Array to give back: {2, 2, 2, 2}

Number: 100
Array to give back: {2, 2, 5, 5}

How can I make a loop that runs until the integer no longer divisible without a remainder?

Comment: so you're saying you want the prime factorization of a number?

Comment: *The numbers are 2, 3,5... all uneven numbers* Two is even. What is the rule for numbers?

Comment: Where is the code you've come up with? We're here to help you with specific problems, not to do your homework for you.

Comment: What you're probably looking for is the lcd (or Least Common Denominators problem). A trivial way to do this is to start dividing a number, n, by the primes, starting with 2. You can tell if n is divisible by i if n % i == 0.

Comment: i dont want you to do the homework for me. i just cant figure out how to make a loop which devides for example 32 by 2 over and over until its no longer mod 0

Comment: Yeah i know @NomandMaker but how can i do that as a loop. i could just do 10000 times if else but isnt there a way to make it easier ?

Comment: 2 is an even number, not an uneven number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute force approach.  Factorization for very large numbers can be very difficult and time consuming and requires special algorithms.  It works by continually dividing by the current prime until the remainder is non-zero.  Then it continues with the next prime.

```
   public static List<Integer> factor(int n) {
        int save = n;
        int[] primes = {2,3,5}; // limited list of primes
        List<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int p : primes) {
            while (n % p == 0) {
             factors.add(p);
             n/=p;
            }
        }
        if (n != 1) {
            System.out.println("Incomplete factorization for " + save);
        }
        return factors;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's your homework, I just give you the idea. You can try to implement.
Note: A non-prime number is divisible by at least a prime number below it.

```
divisible = N
prime = p

loop when (p <= N) {
              check the reminder
              if reminder == !0 {
                 increase p
              }

              if reminder == 0 {
                 store p
                 divide N by p;
              }

 }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try out this function which will calculate the prime numbers of a number.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Factors for 5: " + calculatePrimeFactors(5)); // [5]
    System.out.println("Factors for 16: " + calculatePrimeFactors(16)); // [2, 2, 2, 2]
    System.out.println("Factors for 100: " + calculatePrimeFactors(100)); // [2, 2, 5, 5]
}

public static List<Integer> calculatePrimeFactors(int number) {
    // Create empty factors list
    List<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    // For factor 2; while factor is smaller than the passed number; increase factor
    for(int factor = 2; factor <= number; factor++) {
        // While number % factor equals 0 (fully dividable without rest); add factor and divide number by factor
        while(number % factor == 0) {
            factors.add(factor);
            number = number / factor;
        }
    }
    return factors;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Ill try to understand it